# Add redux-persist on working redux config

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-persist

I could use a little help with the configuration of redux-persist. I have a redux store with two middlewares, the configuration works but I can't add redux-persist properly. either I manage to rehydrate but the actions no longer call the reducer or I have various errors. I find the redux-persist doc a little poor.

Here is my current configuration:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import logger from 'redux-logger';
import allReducer from './reducers';

export default function configureStore() {
  return createStore(
    allReducer,
    applyMiddleware(thunk, logger)
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have finally succeeded, if it helps, here is the configuration to setup:

Store.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import { persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'
import LocalStorage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import logger from 'redux-logger';
import allReducer from './reducers';

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'xxxx-key-xxxx',
  storage: LocalStorage,
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, allReducer)


export default createStore(
  persistedReducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk, logger)
);
```

persistStore.js

```
import { persistStore } from 'redux-persist'
import store from './store';

export default persistStore(store);
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react'
import store from './stores/store';
import persistor from './stores/persistedStore';

import Router from './routes'
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
          <Router/>
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here the list of dependencies and versions

```
"react": "^16.5.2",
"react-dom": "^16.5.2",
"react-redux": "^5.0.7",
"react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
"react-scripts": "2.0.5",
"redux": "^4.0.1",
"redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
"redux-persist": "^5.10.0",
"redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
```

At the moment the named exports do not work so I had to create a second file for the persistor in order to be able to use the default export for the store and the persistor.